# Ruby, create array without key values from existing one

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes as;

```
[{"price" => "123", "amount" => "987"}, {"price" => "432", "amount" => "13"}]
```

I would like to create array of hashes as;

```
[["123", "987"], ["432", "13"]]
```

I have tried `pluck` and `hash.map(&:first).map(&:last)`

I could not achieve what I try to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the key values in each hash by using [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
array_of_hash_objects = [{"price" => "123", "amount" => "987"}, {"price" => "432", "amount" => "13"}]

p array_of_hash_objects.map(&:values)
# [["123", "987"], ["432", "13"]]
```

If using Rails, then I guess you can use pluck but passing the needed attribute values, maybe price and amount:

```
Model.query.pluck(:price, :amount)
```

Note query is the method you're using to get the data.

Comment: What you pass, you get. The order in the hash will be the order of the resulting array.

Comment: `hash.map(&:values)` works perfectly. But you said the resulting array's order can differ? So it can be `[["123", "987"], ["432", "13"]]` or `[["987", "123"], ["13", "432"]]`. But my array of hashes is `[{"price" => "123", "amount" => "987"}, {"price" => "432", "amount" => "13"}]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo What do you mean, the order is undefined? [The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html) says *"Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted"*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I must be mistaken then. I was probably confusing it with some other language's equivalent data structure. My bad.

Comment: If there is any danger the hashes may be provided in an unspecified order (and there is always that danger), you can rely on the keys instead: `array_of_hash_objects.map { |pair| [pair['price'], pair['amount']] }`. This is a less fragile and more appropriate way to navigate a series of Hash objects. Using the suggested solution, if the order changes, your method will fail unexpectedly and silently.